# Finding all paths in graph from one node to another node

Tags: graph, path, scheme, racket

I'm trying to find all the paths between two nodes of the graph. My graph is defined as:

```
(define-struct graph (nodes neighbors node=?))

(define G1 (make-graph '(A B C D E F G)
              (lambda (n)
                (cond [(symbol=? n 'A) '(B E)]
                      [(symbol=? n 'B) '(E F)]
                      [(symbol=? n 'C) '(D)]
                      [(symbol=? n 'D) '()]
                      [(symbol=? n 'E) '(C F A)]
                      [(symbol=? n 'F) '(D G)]
                      [(symbol=? n 'G) '()]))
              symbol=?)))
```

My algorithm is:
1. the main function return a list of list, so I make a recursion on the graph
2. join the source to the paths from its neighbors to the destination.

```
(define (find-paths origination destination G)
  (cond
    [(symbol=? origination destination) (list (list destination))]
    [else (local ((define neighbor ((graph-neighbors G) origination))
                  (define candidate (find-paths/list neighbor destination G)))
            (join origination candidate))]))

(define (find-paths/list lo-Os d g)
  (cond
    [(empty? lo-Os) empty]
    [else (local ((define candidate (find-paths (first lo-Os) d g)))
            (cond
              [(empty? candidate) (find-paths/list (rest lo-Os) d g)]
              [else (append (find-paths (first lo-Os) d g)
                            (find-paths/list (rest lo-Os) d g))]))]))

(define (join node list-of-node)
  (map (lambda (n) (cons node n)) list-of-node))
```

When I test `(find-paths 'A 'E G1)` it returns exactly what I want, which is `(list (list 'A 'E) (list 'A 'B 'E))`. But when I test to `(find-paths 'A 'C G1)` the code stuck and the IDE said it runs out of memory.

Can someone please explain to me why?

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `(displayln (list 'find-paths origination destination))` as the first line of `find-paths` and `(displayln (list 'find-paths/list lo-Os d))` in `find-paths/list`? Probably you'll see it leading back to `(find-paths 'A 'C G1)` and that's your infinite loop. As a guess, check your base case for the empty list?

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop, between 'A and 'E. Because your function tests for every possible path, when you
try to go from 'A to 'C, It will test all the neighbors of 'E getting it back to 'A and from there to 'E again. I have added a `displayln` to show this.

```
(find-pahts A C)
(find-pahts B C)
(find-pahts E C)
(find-pahts C C)
(find-pahts C C)
(find-pahts F C)
(find-pahts D C)
(find-pahts G C)
(find-pahts A C)
(find-pahts B C)
(find-pahts E C)
(find-pahts C C)
(find-pahts C C)
(find-pahts F C)
(find-pahts D C)
(find-pahts G C)
```

As you can see, you have fallen in an infinite loop. It tries 'E 'C, Which leads to 'C 'C which is a path. Then it goes to 'E 'F in turn from 'F it tries 'D and 'G which are both dead ends. And then for the last neighbor of 'E which is 'A, starting all over again.

```
(define (find-paths origination destination G)
  (local ((define (find-paths-ac orig seen)
            (cond
              [(symbol=? orig destination) (list (list destination))]
              [(member orig seen) empty]   ; you can also return an error here. 
              [else (local 
                      ((define neighbor ((graph-neighbors G) orig))
                       (define candidate 
                         (find-paths/list neighbor (cons orig seen))))
                      (join orig candidate))]))

          (define (find-paths/list lo-Os seen)  
            (cond [(empty? lo-Os) empty]
                  [else (local ((define candidate (find-paths-ac (first lo-Os) seen)))
                          (cond [(empty? candidate) (find-paths/list (rest lo-Os) seen)]
                                [else 
                                  (append candidate
                                    (find-paths/list (rest lo-Os) seen))]))]))) 
    (find-paths-ac origination empty)))
```

In this version, I have added an argument to keep track of the nodes I have already seen. And it will
signal an error if it gets to the same node twice (loop).

Comment: But the answer to (find-paths 'A 'C G1) is not an error; in fact there exists a path from A to C.

Comment: It signals an error because you enter an infinite loop. And you said you wanted to find "all paths". If you use `displayln` with it, you can see it finds a path before the error. It is just ignored. My version detects the infinite loop, you can modify it to have a different behavior in that case. I chose to signal an error just to stop the computation.

Comment: for example. If you replace my error message with `empty` it will return 2 paths from 'A to 'C `'(A B E C)` and `'(A E C)`